# Remote git repository for jBPM Business Central

Tags: git, drools, jbpm

I use Business Central from jBPM 7.31 to create assets (BPMN and DMN). In my application (Spring Boot) I attached the KJAR with assets created by Business Central and use KIE as library. In other words, I use BC only as a diagram editor running on localhost.

When I created project in Business Central a new bare git repository was created in $WORKING_DIRECTORY/.niogit directory. However, my team already has a git repository set up. Is it possible to configure Business Central to use a remote git repository instead of the one created on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

We also use business central and briefly looked at doing this. Instead however, we decided it was best to just add an additional remote to the repository because of the lack of support in Business Central and we didn't want to rock the boat.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of jBPM Business Central you can import projects from external git repositories.
[image]

Please note that you can't push local changes back to the repository with the Business Central. You can just do local modifications and deploy them.

If you really need to, you can add a custom "post-commit hook" on Business Central to execute custom commands e.g. push git changes back to your origin.

Comment: For more details about git connection possibilites check out this posts:
* https://porcelli.me/rhba/business-central/git/2018/11/05/business-central-git.html
* https://medium.com/kie-foundation/an-improved-development-workflow-on-business-central-using-our-new-devtools-48fb14f39be9

Comment: When you are interested in creating your assets (e.g. process models or workitemhandler) as java source code checkout: https://github.com/Arvato-Systems/kie4developer

You can host your code in a extra repo and don't need the Business Central alias KIE-Workbench for development and deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the external(remote) git repo in Business Central.

This is described in detail by RedHat in their documentation.

[managing-business-central-git-hooks-con](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.6/html/configuring_business_central_settings_and_properties/managing-business-central-git-hooks-con)

Section also describes setting up Post commit hooks & integrating/importing remote git repositories.